# Retrieving the title of a book with the most authors

Tags: sparql, rdf, ttl

I want to get the information the title of a book with the most authors.
I have used the following query, however I get blank back. If I take them out individually, for example only using title info I will get some  type of data, but having the two together I don't.

```
PREFIX dct: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/> 
PREFIX dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/>


SELECT ?creators ?title (count(?book) as ?count) 
WHERE 
{ ?creators dct:creator ?book .
   ?title dc:title ?book .
} 
      group by ?creators ?title order by desc(?count)
```

Comment: well,  you used the variable `?book` in two patterns, so book is supposed to be the creator of something and a title. In both cases, clearly the direction is wrong, and yes, in RDF this matters, it's a direct (pseudo) graph. do `?book dct:creator ?creators  . ?book dc:title ?title `

Comment: I did try this way beforehand, and I still got no data back from it, which is why i am confused.

Comment: show sample data please, maybe you used `dct:creator` in the other direction, i.e. from creator to book. Then it would be `?creators dct:creator ?book .
   ?book dc:title ?title   .` - but sample data gives me a better overview

Comment: I apologise, I figured it out, it was an error of my prefixs'. May I ask is there away to included `foaf: name` into here so  it can show the name of the author, instead of just the creator?

Comment: well, then just do `?creators foaf:name ?author .` or not? `SELECT ?author ?title (count(?book) as ?count) 
WHERE 
{ ?book dct:creator ?creators . ?book dc:title ?title . ?creators foaf:name ?author .
} 
      group by ?creators ?author ?title`

Comment: Thank you very much  - you have been helpful!